# Unable to write to file, bacuse of permission issue

Tags: python, linux, file-permissions

I have a script (which resides in `/path/to/myscript`) which opens a file and writes to it.

```
outfile = open('/path/to/myfile', 'wb')
```

Now I have the permission to write in `/path/to`. But the users who will run the script do not have write permission. So I did `chmod 666 /path/to/myfile`.

Now everyone should be able to write to `myfile`, but other users are still getting permission denied error on running script.

**Question** - how can I modify the script so anyone is able to write to this file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give mask for this folder

```
umask 000 /path/to
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give read write permission to all user

```
chmod 777 yourscript
```

Comment: Changed permission to 777 for both script and file, but still same error. BTW you changed `myscript` to `yourscript` :p

Comment: what is permission of /path/to/ ?

Comment: the permission for `/path/to` is 755

Comment: `777` is also execute permission which is not needed. `666` IS read and write. I would try changing the folders permission to `777` first.

Answer (score 0):

First find out as which user you are running your script. Then change the user permission of`myfile` directory as that user. If you are running the script as `user1`, then change the permission of your `myfile` directory as,

```
sudo chown user1 /path/to/myfile/
```

You may keep the group permission of the directory as it was before. then give it 666 permission.

Comment: He states that `users` whill be using the file. So changing the owner of the file is not a possibility i would say.

Comment: He is unable of writing a file in the directory from a script for permission issue. Isn't this a approach to solve this?

Comment: What if `user2` needs to write to the file also?